# Can't browse but can ping

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, internet-connection, wan

A couple days ago, abruptly, all devices on my network (2 android phones, a Windows 10 laptop, and a Mac) started having web browsing problems:

- Some sites work fine
- Some sites are very slow
- Some sites (e.g. Facebook) just time out when I try to connect. I also tried entering the IP 31.13.70.36 for Facebook in my browser's address bar, and that didn't work either, so it doesn't seem to be a DNS issue.

I can ping any host fine, but tracert often times out, even on sites that I can connect to.

The Netflix Windows app works fine, but netflix.com doesn't load its stylesheet.

My network looks like this: Thomson DCM475 modem - Asus RT-N12 router - devices.

I've turned everything off and on again -- what else could I do?

Comment: Also check to see that none of the devices are hogging all the bandwidth, such as with updates or something. Also try it without the Mac, as lots of apple devices have some strange notions when it comes to IP networks, and they can crash my router with their invalid data packets. Remember to turn off apple stuff, then reboot modem then reboot router then try the internet, then turn the apple stuff back on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bypass the router, connecting a computer directly to the cable modem. (Be aware that this exposes your computer to the public Internet, so an up-to-date OS and a working firewall are necessary. The Mac may be a more secure option than the Windows box.)
2. Powercycle the cable modem (that is, unplug it from its power for 10 seconds), to get your computer (instead of the router) registering on the network.
3. If the problem is resolved, it was your router. I've found that a factory reset sometimes fixes router problems.
   If, on the other hand, the problem is not resolved, call your ISP. You may be experiencing flops (a physical problem between your modem and the ISP) or a routing problem (a network problem at your ISP or on the Internet). The routing problem is more probable, if you're seeing certain sites and services consistently work and and certain others consistently fail.

Note that the last time I did cable Internet support was in 2007, so some of this troubleshooting may be dated. If in doubt, call your ISP, and they'll walk you through this. (Except for factory resetting your router, probably, which is usually outside of their mandate.)

Comment: Thank you! My ISP TekSavvy, who earlier claimed the problem was probably on my end, now say they're having hitherto ongoing "routing issues" in several regions (including mine) that have lasted for at least a day, so I imagine this is it.